# SMTPAuthenticationError while sending mail using Python

Tags: python, linux, email, automation

when I try to send mail using outlook and python error occurred this type of question is already on this site but doesn't help to me.

```
from redmail import outlook

outlook.user_name = "example@hotmail.com"
outlook.password = "<MY PASSWORD>"

outlook.send(
    receivers=["you@example.com"],
    subject="An example",
    text="Hi, this is an example."
)
```

Error logs:
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [MA0PR01CA0094.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the security vulnerability of OpenSSL.https://www.openssl.org/source/
It seems that Microsoft has restricted the 25 port of SMTP service.
But this problem was solved last night. Now I can normally access both Python and Java.